# Is it possible to write node migrations for D8 alpha/nightly yet?

Tags: 8, migrations

If the migrate api in core is currently capable of doing simple d8-to-d8 migrations, where could I find documentation on how to do so?

This is more or less a learning exercise and I am only trying to migrate standard article nodes from one alpha version to the next.

Comment: Documentation is here https://drupal.org/node/2127611 but I'm sure it's lacking information for obvious reason. Though if you'll look at the migration module you'll see there are Plugin interfaces so you should be able to make something useful with that.

Comment: The [IMP group](https://groups.drupal.org/imp) is also a great source of information and probably the best way to get the latest and greated about the progress being done.

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone. I'll comb back through there and see if I can glean more info.  I was mainly curious b/c there doesn't seem to be a way to run migrations yet either through the UI or Drush.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We haven't written Drupal 8 sources *yet* and they won't be written until Drupal 6 and Drupal 7 is done. It's not a priority. You could, of course, help with writing them :)

Comment: Straight from the man himself! Alrighty then, perhaps I can try once I figure out what I am doing :-)